# Ultra sonic sensor always shows same distance

Tags: arduino, adafruit, nvidia-jetson, arduino-ultra-sonic

I tried to bulid up an ultra sonic sensor and followed this tutorial: https://www.thestrongestlink.nl/2020/05/31/ultrasonic-sensor-for-the-jetbot/#comment-90

In the picture below you can see my wiring.[image]

I uploaded the code from the tutorial to my Feather M0. But when I start the software the display always shows 175 cm (sometimes it fluctuates from 174 to 176).

So next I tried to find the problem. I measured the voltage: at VCC pin are 5V but at TRIG and ECHO is no voltage. I also used two other ultra sonic sensors to see if one is damaged but it is always the same problem.

I dont know why there is no voltage at those two pins and also dont know what to do next or where can be the problem.

Does anyone of you have an idea what to do or what can be the problem?
Thanks

Comment: A) You should post this on Arduino StackExchange and not here where your post is most likely to be voted for closing. B) Add a wiring schema, a drawing, not a photo where it is hard to follow the wires. C) TRIG and ECHO pins works with specific pulses you can't measure with a voltmeter, you would need an oscilloscope and to really know what you are doing. D) Post your code, don't expect anyone to look for it on other sites.

Comment: @Nino thanks for the notice. I will try to add missing information

Answer (score -1):

175cm is the maximum distance the sensor can measure, surelly wiring is wrong or bad pin assignament, post code nd maybe we can help you

Comment: The max range of the sensor is 300 cm.

Comment: Normally the sensor output a very high number like 2000 plus  when facing over range